# Align Text and Image vertically with iText 2

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to print an Image and a text next to each other into a `PdfPCell`. The image is bigger than the font size, so the row height is increased. iText renders the Text at the bottom of the baseline (First example).

But I want the text to be vertically aligned in the middle of the cell (Second example).
What can I do to change this? I know I can change the alignment of the cell, but that doesn't change anything.

```
PdfPCell getImageAndText(byte[] image, String text, int originalDimension){
  final Image pdfImg = Image.getInstance(image);
  //Scale to 16pt.
  pdfImg.scalePercent(16 * 100f / originalDimension);
  Phrase image = new Phrase(new Chunk(pdfImg, 0, 0));
  //Create Cell with image
  final PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(image);
  //Add text to cell
  cell.addElement(new Phrase(text, getFont()));
  return cell;
}
```

I am using iText 2.1.7

[image: What I have and what I want]

Comment: Would you mind if someone gave you an answer how to do this in iText 7.1.2 because nobody still remembers how to do it in that ancient version?

Comment: iText 7.1.2 would be fine as well - Maybe I can adapt the modern solution to my ancient dependency ;)