# How to vertically center some text next to an image in iText 7 PDF

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

There is an image in this question that explains what I want : [Align Text and Image vertically with iText 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50167410/5742135)

Current code

```
    logoCell.add(new Paragraph()
              .add(ImageUtilities.getLogo(15, 15))
               .add("  ABC Company").setFontSize(9)
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
```

What I have:

```
     ______
    |      |
    | image| 
    |______| Text
```

What I need:

```
     ______
    |      |
    | image| Text
    |______|
```

This logo and the text is inside a cell in a Table. They should align horizontally center too. This is currently happening with the code above. 
What I want is to vertically center the image and the text next to it.

iTextPdf 7.1.2